# #validate does not seem to work correctly with :on => :create/:update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

Greetings,

I have a custom validation in my exemplary Movie model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :it, :on => :create

  private

  def it
    self.errors.add 'foo', 'bar'
  end
end
```

This works on movie creation but *also* on updating an existing movie. `:on => :update` will also work for both. Might that be a bug or am I missing something?

Best regards

Tobias

Answer (score 2):

**i think you should use validate_on_create instead**

like

```
validate_on_create :it
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, and only because I saw it in my server console:

> DEPRECATION WARNING:
>   validate_on_create is deprecated.
>   Please use validate(args, :on =>
>   :create).